# How to determine which rule is causing a file to be ignored in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Mercurial is presently ignoring a file which I believe shouldn't be ignored. The `.hgignore` file is remarkably large, and after a cursory read-through it's not obvious which rule(s) is/are the culprit.

Is there a way to get Mercurial to tell me which rules in the .hgignore (if any) match a file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box, but you can write Mercurial extension for this.

I've written extension [hg-isignored](https://bitbucket.org/rpeshkov/hg-isignored) that can show you which rules in .hgignore match specified folder or file.

**Installation**

Clone extension source somewhere, i.e. in `~/.hgrc.d/hg-isignored` folder:

```
hg clone https://hg@bitbucket.org/rpeshkov/hg-isignored ~/.hgrc.d/hg-isignored
```

Add extension in extensions section of your `.hgrc` file:

```
[extensions]
isignored=~/.hgrc.d/hg-isignored/hg-isignored.py
```

Now Mercurial will be able to use `isignored` command that's implemented by extension.

**Usage**

While you're in Mercurial repository, run command `hg isignored PATH`, where instead of PATH insert folder or file that you want to check, i.e. `hg isignored readme.txt`. Extension will tell you if specified PATH is ignored and will show you used rule.

**Testing**

Init

```
[~/hgtest]% hg init
```

No .hgignore

```
[~/hgtest]% touch readme.txt
[~/hgtest]% hg st  
? readme.txt
[~/hgtest]% hg isignored readme.txt
abort: .hgignore file not found
```

Added .hgignore

```
[~/hgtest]% echo "syntax: glob" > .hgignore
[~/hgtest]% echo "readme.txt" >> .hgignore
[~/hgtest]% hg st
? .hgignore
[~/hgtest]% hg isignored readme.txt
Path 'readme.txt' is ignored by:
relglob:readme.txt
```

Not ignored file

```
[~/hgtest]% touch readme2.txt
[~/hgtest]% hg isignored readme2.txt
Path 'readme2.txt' is not ignored
```

Ignore folder

```
[~/hgtest]% mkdir build
[~/hgtest]% touch build/keep.txt
[~/hgtest]% echo "build/" >> .hgignore
[~/hgtest]% hg st
? .hgignore
? readme2.txt
[~/hgtest]% hg isignored build
Path 'build' is ignored by:
relglob:build/
[~/hgtest]% hg isignored build/keep.txt
Path 'build/keep.txt' is ignored by:
relglob:build/
```

Ignore everything in folder

```
[~/hgtest]% echo "syntax: glob" > .hgignore
[~/hgtest]% echo "build/*" >> .hgignore
[~/hgtest]% hg st
? .hgignore
? readme.txt
? readme2.txt
[~/hgtest]% hg isignored build
Path 'build' is not ignored
[~/hgtest]% hg isignored build/keep.txt
Path 'build/keep.txt' is ignored by:
relglob:build/*
```

Comment: Did you write this in response to this question? By your commit history, it looks like you did.. You deserve all the upvotes, sir.

Comment: Yes. I've found your question interesting and started digging Mercurial sources to find out how it works with ignored files.

Comment: I get an error when I run the 'hg isgnored <PATH>' command: "abort: no module named ignore!". It could be a simple fix, but am not sure what this is. The extension seems to be installed because I can run 'hg help isignored'. Can you help?

Comment: @Faredoon which version of Mercurial do you use?

Comment: @black_wizard, I am using version 3.7.3.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as @Faredoon using Mercurial v4.0.2

Comment: @ShawndeWet, I've updated extension so now it should work with Mercurial 4. Sorry for so sloooow update :) I'm currently not using Mercurial.

Comment: FYI if you didn't have an existing `.hgrc` you need to add the path to the command to an "[extensions]" block or else you will get "unknown command" error.

Comment: @swanson yep, all custom extensions have to be added to config file